# How to cumulatively add time

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have time interval in minutes.

```
dfr <- data.frame(interval=c(rep("30",2),rep("60",2)),stringsAsFactors=F)

>> dfr
  interval
1       30
2       30
3       60
4       60
```

And I have a start time, say 09:00.

```
time_begin <- "09:00"
```

I would like to start with `time_begin` and cumulatively add intervals to get the result below:

```
  interval start   end
1       30 09:00 09:30
2       30 09:30 10:00
3       60 10:00 11:00
4       60 11:00 12:00
```

What is the best way to do this using dplyr/lubridate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `lubridate` we can first create `end` column by starting with `time_begin` and adding  cumulative sum of `interval` `minutes` and use those values to get `start` time.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

dfr %>%
  mutate(end = time_begin + minutes(cumsum(interval)), 
         start = c(time_begin, end[-n()]))

#  interval                 end               start
#1       30 2019-04-20 09:30:00 2019-04-20 09:00:00
#2       30 2019-04-20 10:00:00 2019-04-20 09:30:00
#3       60 2019-04-20 11:00:00 2019-04-20 10:00:00
#4       60 2019-04-20 12:00:00 2019-04-20 11:00:00
```

where

```
time_begin <- as.POSIXct("09:00:00", format = "%T")
```

The above has today's date in the output. To get exactly same output as yours we can `format` the output

```
dfr %>%
  mutate(end = time_begin + minutes(cumsum(interval)), 
         start = c(time_begin, end[-n()]), 
         start = format(start, "%T"), 
         end = format(end, "%T")) %>%
  select(interval, start, end)

#  interval    start      end
#1       30 09:00:00 09:30:00
#2       30 09:30:00 10:00:00
#3       60 10:00:00 11:00:00
#4       60 11:00:00 12:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do this without any external packages

```
v1 <- with(dfr, format(strptime(time_begin, "%H:%M") + 
               c(0, cumsum(as.integer(interval) *60)), "%H:%M"))
transform(dfr, start = v1[-length(v1)], end = v1[-1])
#  interval start   end
#1       30 09:00 09:30
#2       30 09:30 10:00
#3       60 10:00 11:00
#4       60 11:00 12:00
```